# Quarkus code generator 2.2.5 with quarkus 3.1.0.Final gives `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Tags: openapi, quarkus, openapi-generator

I am getting the below error on using the `io.quarkiverse.openapi.generator:quarkus-openapi-generator:2.2.5` with quarkus `3.1.0.Final`. The application starts and works as expected but the error is displayed in the logs.

```
DEBUG [io.qua.dep.uti.FSWatchUtil] (FSWatchUtil) Failed checking for code gen source modifications: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: PROJECT_LOCATION\build\classes\java\openapi
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:199)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:220)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:277)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:323)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:71)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3918)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3973)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.util.FSWatchUtil.doObserve(FSWatchUtil.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.util.FSWatchUtil.lambda$observe$1(FSWatchUtil.java:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Is there any configuration that needs to be added? I have seen in https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/pull/3359 that we can have `<extensions>true</extensions>` in plugin but I use gradle.

I tried to find a proper solution but wasn't successful.

Comment: This is a `DEBUG` level logging that the internal core Quarkus Codegen API is spamming trying to find a new openapi file to generate code. We can't control it from the extension point of view. You can disable the DEBUG log level, it's not an error. If it finds a new file to generate code, it won't spam the log.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create the missing folder `src/main/openapi`.
It works with no file inside.